# Grails read from one domain to another domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I created 2 domain class which is

Duty.groovy:

```
    class Duty {
               String username
               String duty
    }
```

User.groovy:

```
    class User {
               String username
    }
```

I already assigned some users in Bootstrap.groovy, I want to create a duty list function to assigned duty to users. So in my duty list, it should include a drop-down list which contains list of users from User domain.

But when I import testApp.User at my gsp (in Duty domain) file and created a taglib to display the userlist, my compiler shows that No such property. I would like to ask for suggestions for best way to display the list of users from my Duty domain to User domain?

Here is other code:
SelectUserTagLib.groovy

```
    import HR_System.User
    def userInstance = new User()
    def displayType = { attrs,body -> 
    def name = attrs.name 

    out << "<select id=\"${name}\" name=\"${name}\" require=\"\" >"
    out << "<g:each in='${userInstanceList}'' status='i' var='userInstance'>"
    out << "<option value=\"${name}\">${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "username")}</option>"
    out << "</g:each>"
    out << "</select>"
}
```

_form.gsp:

```
    <name:displayType name="username" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't really need custom taglib for such purpose.
You can do it with simple g:select.

```
<g:select name="user"
          from="${User.list()}"/>
```

You can read about it in grails docs: https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html.

Please ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, it works, but my results shows <option value="User(username:User Name1)"> instead of <option value="User Name1">. May I know how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: "By default, the value attribute of each <option> element will be the result of a toString() call on each element." -- from docs. 
You can specify optionKey="username", so code will look like this: <g:select name="user" from="${User.list()}" optionKey="username"/>.

Comment: I added optionKey and the code is <option value="User Name1">, but I want it still shows like as <option value="User Name1">User(username:User Name1)</Option>. Anyway to change it?

Comment: Pavel, I have solve the issue by adding optionValue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you adjust your model to be really a domain model so it looks like:

```
    class User {
               String username
    }

    class Duty {
               User user
               String duty
    }
```

then Grails would scaffold the GSP-view for your `Duty` class automagically with the `User`-dropdown included